# Meteor.js persistent + memory Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, imdb

It's possible to connect meteor manually to 2 or more databases in order to have a normal mongo that saves to the disk and a memory one like redis?

I'm asking because mongo has already full support from meteor and using it would be a lot easier than redis or other database

Comment: You should search on https://atmospherejs.com --- here https://atmospherejs.com/package/redis --  you need to know about Meteorite to install it

Comment: I'm saying about using mongo because of it's reactivity. Redis has that too with pub/sub, but it lacks the collection features that meteor uses for mongo

Answer (score 1):

Right now, a Meteor server can only connect to one (and exactly one) Mongo database.

[Redis support](https://trello.com/c/sWcxRwxN/31-redis-support) is on the roadmap, as is [SQL support](https://trello.com/c/Gf6YxFp2/42-sql-support). Once Meteor supports multiple databases, you will have more options for how to set up your databases as well as dividing up your data between them. The only way to do what you are saying right now is to have your Meteor client connect to two different Meteor servers, and have one of them clear/dump the database regularly.

*Source: discussions at Meteor's offices.*